# Set img border to push the next image in the list

Tags: html, css, image

I have a bit of a problem with css.

I have a forum, that the images in the forum don't have a border, I have to use `min-hight` so thy will not go behind the next one.

I want that the size of the `img`, will be the border, and not the `min-hight` to be the border.

My forum- limodim.com/1

Image of what im talking about

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mU3G09L.png]

```css
 `.forum-blocks dl.icon .forum-image {
 text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;

}`


.rtl .forum-image {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 5px;
}


.forum-image {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_forum_row_prepend -->
        <dl class="icon {forumrow.FORUM_IMG_STYLE}">
            <dt title="{forumrow.FORUM_FOLDER_IMG_ALT}">
                <!-- IF forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE --><div class="forum-image">{forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE}</div><!-- ENDIF -->
```

```
    <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_forum_row_prepend -->
        <dl class="icon {forumrow.FORUM_IMG_STYLE}">
            <dt title="{forumrow.FORUM_FOLDER_IMG_ALT}">
                <!-- IF forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE --><div class="forum-image">{forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE}</div><!-- ENDIF -->
```

thank you

Comment: post your html and css as well for clear understanding.

Comment: i don't know what htnl/css lines exactly that part uses
what i have manage to do, is to take the .forum-blocks dl.icon and add a min-hight of 110, but it is making to much space in the small catagoris.
so i need that the min-hight will go on the image css and will push the next under item (witout pushing the forums in side it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have edit it, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your forum and I think adding the following css will help you achieve what you want:

```
.forum-blocks dl.icon .forum-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then you should add `max-height` to your `img` as following

```
.forum-blocks dl.icon .forum-image img{
        max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast replay.  it resize the img, instade keeping it size and pushing the one under it. maby have another option to push the one under it? while keeping the forums in side it